# modify this code to support another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I found this code (written in appdelegate for an application). All I want is to just let it support one more view ( I created it).

The code :

```
- (IBAction)swap
{
    NSArray *subs = [window subviews];
    [[subs objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    if([subs objectAtIndex:0] == view2){
        [window addSubview:view1];
    } else if([subs objectAtIndex:0] == view1){
        [window addSubview:view2];
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote second else if with addSubview:view3 but it didn't work :(

Comment: but what should it do? what's the goal? now it just remove first view and swap with a new one (swapping view1 with view2 and viceVersa)... do you mean it's not working or that you want to do something else? and what, in case? explain it better, please...  swap between 3 views?

Comment: @meronix all I want swap between 3 views and i got it thank u everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)swap
{
    NSArray *subs = [window subviews];
    UIView *currentView = (UIView *)[subs objectAtIndex:0];
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    if(currentView == view1){
        [window addSubview:view2];
    } else if(currentView == view2){
        [window addSubview:view3];
    } else 
        [window addSubview:view1];
    }
}
```

Comment: great and thx another question when I use it should I do something for memory management or it work fine ??

Comment: @Bobj-C your memory management should be fine in the method above since you are not creating anything (just working with references). Since you have created those views elsewhere, be sure to release them in your dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming views 1, 2, and 3 are the only views -

```
- (IBAction)swap
{
    [window sendSubviewToBack:[[window subviews] lastObject]];
}
```

Or, reversing the direction

```
- (IBAction)swap
{
    [window bringSubviewToFront:[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to torture your self with IF ELSEs you could use an array of views and iterate through them.

```
NSArray *myViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, nil];

NSInteger nextIndex = [myViews indexOfObject:[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0]] + 1;

nextIndex = (nextIndex % [myViews count]); // to loop around if reached the end
[window addSubview:[myViews objectAtIndex:nextIndex]];
```

You can do something smart about the array of views so you do not recreate it every time you swap.

Comment: thank you if I want  to make a special class to View2 to put in it the methods ... what should i do ?